# PHP Syntax in functions

Tags: php, syntax

I am using a loop to go through the result of query and display the data in a grid. I only want to display the delete button in certain rows. I can setup if else statements for that.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//HTML code - I am not using echo here just plain html code written below

deleteButton();//I am calling the deleteButton function here.

//HTML code

}
```

I have a deleteButton function at the top of the page

```
function deleteButton()
{
echo "<form name='DeleteInfo' method='POST' action='delete.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val1' value=$rows[col1]>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value=$rows[col2]>";
echo "<input class='center' type='submit' value='Delete'/>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

I get an error undefined variable rows for col1 and col2. I am assuming it's a syntax problem.

I have also tried.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value=$rows['col2']>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value='$rows[col2]'>";
```

This HTML code works

```
<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="<?php echo $rows['col3']; ?>">
```

EDIT: Resolved. It was out of scope. I have to use global $rows in the function. Thanks Marc.

Comment: If anyone is wondering deleteButton call is within PHP Tags.

Comment: In other words, pass $rows as a parameter to deleteButton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $rows variable doesn't exist in the scope of the deleteButton function.  You could amend it like this:

```
function deleteButton($rows) {
    // etc
}
```

and then call it as:

```
deleteButton($rows);
```

Comment: This works too. I forgot the pass the parameter. Setting up $rows as global will work but I think this is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

As Steven pointed out, you have to pass $rows into the function as well.

Full example:

```
function deleteButton($row)
{
    echo "<form name='DeleteInfo' method='POST' action='delete.php'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val1' value={$rows['col1']}>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value={$rows['col2']}>";
    echo "<input class='center' type='submit' value='Delete'/>";
    echo "</form>";
}

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    // ...

    deleteButton($rows);

    // ...

}
```

You could wrap your array accessor in braces or use concatenation

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value={$rows['col2']}>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value=".$rows['col2'].">";
```

Comment: Actually the manual page you linked states that the way he used it is correct.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Too true, I jumped the gun a bit. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Variables do not stay in scope from one function to the next. If you have a variable that you want to use in a function that you're calling, then you need to pass that variable into the function. (the other option is to make them global, but I'll ignore that, as it's not a good idea to overuse globals)

So where you call the function, you need to call it like this:

```
deleteButton($rows);
```

...and then in the function declaration, you need to add it there as well, like this:

```
function deleteButton($rows)
```

This is fairly basic stuff as far as PHP goes, or indeed programming in general. It would be good for you to get a handle on this kind of thing, make sure you understand it properly befoe you write too much more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value=".$rows['col2'].">";
```

Answer (score -1):

$rows is not accessable from that function, so what you can do is either pass it as an argument to that function, for make the $rows GLOBAL, by defining it outside any scope and putting the statement

```
global $rows;
```

in the functions where you want to access it.

Comment: @Brian: I was just showing two(passing arguments, Global variables) of the various ways he could use to solve his problem.

Comment: I guess then you know that globals can become a very bad habit, hence the down-vote for teaching bad habits - if you had mentioned to use as a 'last resort' - would have been OK :)